# Jenkins: Build all commits triggered by push

Tags: git, jenkins, automated-testing

How can I make Jenkins build all new commits (not just the latest) when there is a push?
Note: The push is the trigger for the Job

Comment: This really is probably not what you want. Some people commit after every few keystrokes...

Comment: But what if you'd like to configure that?

Comment: And what type of VCS are you using? Github/Gitlab/BitBucket/gitolite/etc?

Comment: I am using BitBucket